# Debug tool to track size of all STL containers in program?

Tags: c++, debugging, stl

Is there anything that can be done to track the size of every container in my C++ program? I have a program that has to be run real-time to actually work and in which memory grows over time probably due to STL containers I have forgotten to clean up nodes from when I am done with them.

They aren't proper memory leaks but there are plenty of containers in which I write data, do stuff with it for a while, erase entries (which I am not consistently doing it seems) and move on. I want to see if I can track down which containers I have forgotten to clean up. I apologize for what I'm sure must be a duplicate question, but I could not for the life of me find an answer.

Limitations:

- I have to run my program real-time or it will drastically change the course of the program.
- I don't have an IDE set up to run my code
- It has to run on Linux

I am sadly limited to those and I can't change that. Any ideas shy of grepping each instance of vector etc and putting a print in the code?

Comment: Have you tried [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: @JerryCoffin The real-time constraint will severely limit the ability to use valgrind right?

Comment: @Ben: Depends on exactly how real-time it needs to be. If he can't put up with any slowdown at all, then yes, he's probably out of luck. If he can put up with some, then at least some of valgrind's tools *may* be acceptable (depending on how much he can put up with).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I guess just out of personal use, the huge amount of debug flags that valgrind lays down has always caused issues with my real time programs. I would be interested in tools that vg offers that dont cause this issue.

Comment: I've not heard of a tool to do this, but you could modify your Standard Library headers momentarily (make a private build of the compiler if you can't or don't want to modify the normal install's headers), just logging size when the container's resized (for e.g. vector, unordered containers that grow in chunks), or passes thresholds you track yourself (for lists, maps).  Or just have the containers register themselves with some list you can use to get snapshots of size.  That might be easier than modifying thousands of source locations specifying the containers.

Comment: You can try compiling (under clang or gcc) with the memory sanitizer (msan), supposedly similar to valgrind but only factor of two slow down.

Comment: @TonyD that's a great idea. Create a base class that registers its pointer into a global list in the constructor, deregisters itself in the destructor, and has a virtual method to get the container size. Then have all the container classes derive from that base, and fill in the virtual function. P.S. it shouldn't require a special build of the compiler, all the containers are template classes which will be defined in a header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One interesting approach that is potentially quite powerful and performant, but a non-trivial amount of work, is to write a custom allocator. Start with the minimal allocator, described here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator. You can then add two key things: first, on construction, you can get a backtrace (e.g. https://panthema.net/2008/0901-stacktrace-demangled/, there are many resources online for this), and log the backtrace along with the `this` pointer. Then, on every allocate and deallocate call, you can log the size of the allocation/deallocation along with the this pointer.

Ultimately, your log file will contain all the allocations and deallocation sizes mapped by pointer, and a backtrace that will let you figure out what object in your code each pointer corresponds to. You can add additional logging statements to get a sense of where these are occuring relative to program control flow. Then, you can easily write a python script that will do running sums of allocations/deallocations to see what the sizes of your containers are at various points in your program.

Once you write the custom allocator you'll of course need to use it everywhere, which is slightly annoying but not too difficult. Preferably factor out your container types into typedefs in a central header file so its each to change back to the standard allocator afterwards.

Comment: Nice idea.  Still, *"use it everywhere, which is slightly annoying but not too difficult"* - unless you need to pass instances into some binary-only out-of-line library functions: then your custom allocators will have changed your types and not match the library header or the symbols in the library.

Comment: @Tony D Yeah, sounds annoying. The good news is that the allocator I suggested is stateless, so it will not change the memory layout of vector, guaranteed. So you can write the allocator separately and make sure it works, then copy and paste it into your standard library to use as std:: allocator. Not elegant but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions. You are probably right that the only way is to actually edit the allocator and add my own code.

In the end, since Valgrind was too slow, I tried gperftools which was also too slow but at least fast enough to get me a little bit of a clue of what is happening in my code. Thanks all for the suggestions.